# Permission denied error in app engine code

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting the below error in the line 5 while executing the app engine code in localhost and in cloud.

```
1   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
2       GetMethod getMethod =new GetMethod(url);
3       client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams()
4       .setConnectionTimeout(1000);
5       int response = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
```

I am seeing this error while running the job in localhost and in app engine.

Please find the error logs below:

```
INFO] 2016-03-07 11:04:03 DEBUG HttpConnection:1215 - enter HttpConnection.closeSockedAndStreams()
[INFO] 2016-03-07 11:04:03 INFO  HttpMethodDirector:439 - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Permission denied: Not allowe
d to issue a socket bind: permission denied.
[INFO] 2016-03-07 11:04:03 DEBUG HttpMethodDirector:443 - Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket bind: permission denied.
[INFO] java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket bind: permission denied.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:95)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:106)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:74)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.createSocket(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:470)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.bind(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:486)
[INFO]  at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:631)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:139)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
[INFO]  at com.disney.unityads.UnityAdsStats.downloadZip(UnityAdsStats.java:169)
[INFO]  at com.disney.unityads.UnityAdsStats.run(UnityAdsStats.java:72)
[INFO]  at com.disney.unityads.UnityAdsChannelJobWorker.doPost(UnityAdsChannelJobWorker.java:46)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for how to make HTTP requests. AppEngine is a very limited environment, for example if you try to use an alternative HTTP client your app gets the same treatment as one that tries to use sockets directly.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/